# How to use windows default file browser in kivy app

Tags: python, kivy, file-browser

I am developing a kivy application and for file uploads i would like to use the windows default file browser, and not the ones offered by kivy (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html). Do you know if that is even possible? I haven't found anything around. Thanks.

The functions that are actually working with kivy default file browser is the following:

```
def show_load(self):
    content = LoadDialog(load=self.load_file,cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
    self._popup = Popup(
        title='Load file', content=content, size_hint=(0.9, 0.9)
    )
    self._popup.open()

def load_file(self, path, filename):
    self.filename = filename

    full_path = os.path.join(path, filename[0])

    filename = os.path.basename(full_path)

    app = App.get_running_app()
    self.check_input(full_path)

    self.dismiss_popup()

def check_input(self, filepath):
    '''Auxiliary method for checking user input.
    '''
    data_df = load_dataframe(filepath, self.ftypes, sep=';')

    if not isinstance(data_df, pd.DataFrame) and data_df == -999:
        self.warning_popup(message='File format not accepted')

    elif data_df.empty:
        self.warning_popup(message='Empty file')

    # If everything is OK
    else:
        self.data_df = data_df
        self.filepath = filepath
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a workaround based on tkinter, see my example app below.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string("""
<rootwi>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    PathButton:
        on_press: label.text = self.get_path()
    Label:
        id: label

""")
class PathButton(Button):
    @staticmethod
    def get_path():
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.withdraw()

        return( filedialog.askopenfilename() )

class rootwi(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return rootwi()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use filechooser from [Kivy Plyer](https://github.com/kivy/plyer). Make sure you already install Kivy Plyer using `pip install plyer`. You can try below code in Python console.

```
from plyer import filechooser
path = filechooser.open_file(title="Pick a CSV file..", 
                             filters=[("Comma-separated Values", "*.csv")])
print(path)
```